# Python - azure-devops - AssignedTo field is missing

Tags: python, azure-devops, ado

I wrote a python function retrieving the results from an **ADO query**

```
def get_query_results(connection, project_name,query_id):

   '''
   Gets the result of a query in ADO
   '''
   results = []
   try:
      wit_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()
      result = wit_client.query_by_id(query_id)

      work_items = result.work_items

      for work_item in work_items:
         work_item_details = wit_client.get_work_item(id=work_item.id, fields=["System.Id", "System.Title","System.AssignedTo"], expand="Relations,Fields")
         results.append({"id": work_item_details.fields['System.Id'], "title": work_item_details.fields['System.Title'], "assigned_to": work_item_details.fields['System.AssignedTo']})
   except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(f'Error fetching repositories from {project_name}: {str(e)}')

   return results
```

but although there are a lot of available fields like "Assigned To" in ADO ui, it seems I cannot get **AssignedTo** field

```
results.append({"id": work_item_details.fields['System.Id'], "title": work_item_details.fields['System.Title'], "assigned_to": work_item_details.fields['System.AssignedTo']})
KeyError: 'System.AssignedTo'
```

- how can I fix this ?
- how can I retrieve the available fields instead of just guessing ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the function "**`wit_client.get_work_item`**" to get a work item in Python, if this work item is not assigned to any user, the output of the function will not contain the '**`System.AssignedTo`**' field. In this situation, the "**`work_item_details.fields['System.AssignedTo']`**" will return the error message "**`KeyError: 'System.AssignedTo'`**".

To avoid this error, you can try to use the function like as below.

```py
work_item = wit_clinet.get_work_item(xxx)
work_item_assigned_to = work_item.fields.get('System.AssignedTo')
```

- If the work item has been assigned to a user, it will return the content of '**`System.AssignedTo`**'.
- If the work item is not assigned to any user, it will return '**`None`**' instead of an error.

---

**EDIT:**

Below is the Python script sample I tested on my side, and it can work well as stated above:

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication

personal_access_token = '{personal_access_token}'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}'
query_id = '{query_id}'

credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

wit_clinet = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()
query_result = wit_clinet.query_by_id(query_id)

work_items = query_result.work_items
for wit in work_items:
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------')
    print(f'Getting work item by Id: {wit.id}')
    work_item = wit_clinet.get_work_item(id=wit.id, fields=["System.Id", "System.Title","System.AssignedTo"], expand="Relations,Fields")
    work_item_assigned_to = work_item.fields.get('System.AssignedTo')
    print(work_item_assigned_to)
```

---

Comment: AttributeError: 'WorkItemReference' object has no attribute 'fields'

Comment: tried work_item_assigned_to = work_item.as_dict()['System.AssignedTo'], but no AssignedTo field is present

Comment: @pf12345678910, I have updated my above answer with a Python script sample (see **EDIT**). Reference it and try in your Python script.